# Clearing button Array

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, visual-studio-2010, button

I am creating a grid of buttons using the following code:

```
Button[][] buttons;
```

In the method:

```
for (int r = 0; r < row; r++)
    {
       for ( int c = 0; c < col; c++)
           {
             buttons[r][c] = new Button();
           }
    }
```

How can I clear and reset `buttons[][]` if `row` or `col` changes, is there away to do it?

Comment: What do you mean clear and reset?

Comment: In the same way you clear an array.. maybe I'm trying to do somethings that doesn't exist

Comment: `buttons` is an array.  You can just set the element to `null`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is. You can call the [`Array.Clear()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clear.aspx) function. Since your array holds `Button` objects, which are reference types, it will reset every item in the array to `null`.

```
Array.Clear(buttons, 0, buttons.Length);
```

However, I *strongly* suggest using one of the generic containers for this, rather than a raw array. For example, a [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) would be a good choice. In your case, `T` would be `Button`.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;  // required at the top of the file for List<T>

List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
```

To use it like a two-dimensional array, you will need a nested list (basically, a `List` that contains a `List` that contains `Button` objects). The syntax is a little intimidating, but it's not so hard to figure out what it means:

```
List<List<Button>> buttons = new List<List<Button>>();
```

Comment: @Hogan You can declare a `List<List<Button>>` which operates pretty much the same.

Comment: @cody how do I populate the List<List<>>

Answer (score -1):

you can invoke Clear() Method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clear.aspx